# Call an Identity Provider API post Auth0 authentication

Tags: auth0

I am trying to follow the list of set of steps at https://auth0.com/docs/what-to-do-once-the-user-is-logged-in/calling-an-external-idp-api but despite my best effort am not able to get the access token as I am getting a error as follows:

```
POST https://r***s.eu.auth0.com/oauth/token 401 (Unauthorized)
```

when I try to obtain the access token.

My code is the following:

```
var data = {
    client_id : '****',
    client_secret : '****',
    audience : 'https://r****.eu.auth0.com/api/v2/',
    grant_type : 'client_credentials'
};

var config = {
            json: true,
            headers : {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json;'
 };
        }

$http.post('https://r***.eu.auth0.com/oauth/token',data, config).then ( 
    function(response) { console.log(response); } 
        );
```

Comment: The `401` error you are getting seems to indicate that the payload (body) of the request contains incorrect or missing values for `client_id` and `client_secret`.
Without providing the actual `client_secret` (which is :) secret), can you give more information on how are you calling the `/oauth/token` endpoin?

Comment: As per the list of actions in the guide on Auth0 website i created a "non-interactive" application and am using the client ID and secret of that application in my payload.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're setting an incorrect `Content-Type` when doing your `POST` request.

The correct content type for a JSON request is the following: **`application/json`**

You're appending an extra **`;`** character at the end which is causing the server to issue a 401 response.

Additionally, that code snippet seems to be from an AngularJS application. If that's the case there's two additional problems, due to CORS limitation unless the application domain is white-listed in the *Allowed Origins (CORS)* list in the client settings (Auth0 Dashboard), you won't be able to perform the request anyway. This is the first problem, but not the biggest one... **if you solve this by adding the domain to the white-list you now have a client identifier and secret stored on a client-side application** which means anyone can access it just by looking at the code. **In almost all (probably 99.9%) situations this is just wrong.**